# Send mail for multiple user and the each recipents have only his email address not the others

Tags: email, sendgrid

I am new bie for send grid. I have checked this url for two emails "https://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.js..." and got the mail successfully in both emails.

The mail received by the users from the above URL have both email address in "TO" field like
For ex. User Test To: test@example.com;test2@example.com. and For User test2 To: test@example.com;test2@example.com.

As per my requirement i want to send mail for multiple user and the each recipents have only his email address not the others.
For ex. User Test To: test@example.com and For User test2 To: test2@example.com.

Can this scenario is possible with send grid.

Thanks

Comment: The API link you posted doesn't work @ the moment, but aren't you just needing to BCC the recipients rather than using TO? ANd not quite sure how this relates to ColdFusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send the same email to multiple recipients by using the [SendGrid SMTP API's `to` parameter](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html#-The-XSMTPAPI-Header).

To do this you'll set an `X-SMTPAPI:` header in your message, this header will include the JSON to communicate with SendGrid's SMTP API. The header will look as such:

```
X-SMTPAPI: { "to": [ "test@example.com", "test2@example.com" ] }
```

Each recipient will receive a unique email, addressed *only* to them.

Be aware: you'll still need to set a `To:` header for the message to send, however you can set this to yourself or one of the recipients (and then exclude them from the JSON list).

Comment: Hey Nick, I did what you suggested in the comment, but it delivered the email to the address mentioned in the "to" header and not the ones in the x-smtpapi header.

Comment: @codeinprogress Likely, you're running into a formatting issue. I'd create your own question so we can help to answer it.

Comment: Hey @NickQ. Can I use bcc also in X-SMTPAPI header? I have used X-SMTPAPI for `to`. Please anyone reply.

Comment: Ankit, you cannot use BCC in the `X-SMTPAPI` header, only `to`. If you wish to use `BCC` you should send messages individually.

Answer (score 0):

Send grid being a standard SMTP server will respond as if you are sending email from gmail, yahoo or outlook.

The scenario is not possible that I am aware of.  I have only incorporated it into 2 applications, so I am certain there are better experts.

As an alternative you could test using the blind copy, The problem with that is would need a main address in the To field, which may not fill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Send email on Azure Mobile Service /NodeJS

```
 var sendgrid = new SendGrid('KEY');
sendgrid.send({
    to: toEMail, // ["email1@mail.com", "email2@mail.com",...]
    from: fromEMail,
    subject: subject,
    text: body
}, function (success, message) {
    console.log("send mail: " + subject);
    // If the email failed to send, log it as an error so we can investigate
    if (!success) {
        console.error(message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

possible on Sendgrid. You can use the normal bcc on sendgrid via personalization, but we dont like it because the `To:` is always required. So my solution is sendgrid transactional email. This will send 1 email to multiple users (using sendgrid / php / laravel ):

```
    $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
    $email->setFrom("sender@mail.com", "Sender Name");
    $email->setSubject("Your subject");
    $email->addTo(
        "email.1@mail.com",
        "User One",
        [],
        0
    );
    $email->addTo(
        "email.2@mail.com",
        "User Two",
        [],
        1
    );
    $email->addTo(
        "email.3@mail.com",
        "User Three",
        [],
        2
    );
    $email->addContent("text/plain", "your body");
    $email->addContent("text/html", "<strong>your body</body>");

    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
    try {
        $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
        return response()->json($response, 200);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 400);
    }
```